# C++ Compare words between 2 different text files

Tags: c++, text-files, fstream, string-comparison

I have 2 text files:

1. Main file: Library.txt
2. File to compare: fileToCompare.txt

The main file(**Library.txt**) contains a lot of words, but still not a complete one. So I search online to find more words and save them in **fileToCompare.txt**. But there must be many same words in Library.txt & fileToCompare.txt, so to eliminate the same words I need to compare **fileToCompare.txt** with **Library.txt** to determine which words are the same.
My way to eliminate the same words is compare each word one by one with Library.txt. That means let say if the first word is "apple", then "apple" will compare each word 1 by 1 in Library.txt and when it finds it, "apple" is the same word occurs in these 2 files. If not found, "apple" will be `cout` in the console and save it the text file (which asked user before to enter the file name to save non-existing words).
I found out that if **fileToCompare.txt** contains many words e.g. 1mb of file size, it takes an hour to compare all the words. So I think out a way:

1. **fileToCompare.txt** is sorted alphabetically, so it always start from alphabet "a" (if it is). It compares as usual and when it reach alphabet "b", it create another text file **Library2.txt** in "lib/" directory.
2. I `ofstream` all the words start from alphabet "b" to **Library2.txt**. And now instead of comparing with the main file, it compares with **Library2.txt**. Or I can say **Library2.txt** is the main file now.
3. The comparison process continued start from alphabet "b" and if it reached alphabet "c", it create another text file **Library3.txt** and `ofstream` all the words start from alphabet "c" and so on... till the end of word start from "z" obviously, which is end of comparison process.

But the problem is it won't eliminate same words, actually some does, but many don't. I checked the main file and some words in the output file are the same.
Here is the download link for **Library.txt** & **fileToCompre.txt** if you need it:
Library.txt -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/ihqpaju3b33ysgv/Library.txt?dl=0

fileToCompre.txt -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/pioy77g9mfz9och/fileToCompare.txt?dl=0

What I explain above might be confusing and the code is quite messy actually, I know it's hard to understand, sure to take you a whole evening to figure out.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string txt="fileToCompare.txt";
    ifstream lib;
    lib2.open(txt.c_str());
    if(!lib2){
        cout<<"\n Oops! "<<txt<<" is missing!\n If such file exists, be sure to check the file extension is .txt\n";
        getch();
        main();
    }
    cout<<"\n Enter the file name to save the non-existing words\n (required an extension at the end)\n";
    getline(cin,word);
    string libPath="lib/"+word,alphaStr="a",libtxt[26]={"Library.txt","lib/Library2.txt","lib/Library3.txt","lib/Library4.txt","lib/Library5.txt","lib/Library6.txt","lib/Library7.txt","lib/Library8.txt","lib/Library9.txt","lib/Library10.txt","lib/Library11.txt","lib/Library12.txt","lib/Library13.txt","lib/Library14.txt","lib/Library15.txt","lib/Library16.txt","lib/Library17.txt","lib/Library18.txt","lib/Library19.txt","lib/Library20.txt","lib/Library21.txt","lib/Library22.txt","lib/Library23.txt","lib/Library24.txt","lib/Library25.txt","lib/Library26.txt"};
    const char* wordChar=libPath.c_str();
    const char* libManip=libtxt[0].c_str();
    int alphaI=1,boolcheck=1;
    lib.open(libManip);
    outWord.open(wordChar);
    while(getline(lib2,libStr2)){
        if(libStr2.substr(0,1)!=alphaStr){
            lib.close();
            lib.open(libManip);
            libMO.open(libtxt[alphaI].c_str());
            while(getline(lib,libStr)){
                if(libStr.substr(0,1)!=alphaStr){
                    libMO<<libStr<<endl;
                }
            }
            libManip=libtxt[alphaI].c_str();
            libMO.close();
            lib.close();
            alphaI++;
            alphaStr=libStr2.substr(0,1);
            boolcheck=1;
        }
        if(boolcheck==1){
            lib.close();
            lib.open(libManip);
            boolcheck=0;
        }
        while(getline(lib,libStr)){
            if(libStr==libStr2){
                found=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            cout<<"\n "<<libStr2;
            outWord<<libStr2<<endl;
            countNF++;
        }
        count++;
        found=0;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n\n Total words: "<<count<<"\n Total words reserved: "<<countNF;
    lib2.close();
    lib.close();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not tag C if your question is about C++, especially since you have `std::string`, `<fstream>`, and `<iostream>`

Comment: Your code looks too complicated to be right for this task.

Comment: You need an appropriate data structure, like std::set or a hash map (std::unordered_set). Right now you have O(MN) time complexity where M, N are the number of words in your two files. A hash map would lower that to O(M+N).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different algorithm / data structure for the comparison.
The following example uses a `std::set`. It reads both files and writes the merged result into `merged.txt`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
   std::ifstream lib("Library.txt");;

   std::set<std::string> lib_set;
   std::string word;
   while (lib >> word)
   {
      lib_set.insert(word);
   }

   std::ifstream check("fileToCompare.txt");
   while (check >> word)
   {
      lib_set.insert(word);
   }

   std::ofstream merged("merged.txt");

   std::set<std::string>::iterator it;
   for (it = lib_set.begin(); it != lib_set.end(); ++it)
   {
       merged << *it << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Executing this for your dataset takes 0.8 seconds on my computer.

Comment: so that basically works fine, but instead of merging the results i would like to count how many words eliminated in fileToCompare.txt, and maybe  `cout` on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Since the files fileToCompare.txt and Library.txt are sorted alphabetically, your code can take advantage of that.

1. Read a word from each file.
2. If the two words are same, read the next words from the files.
3. If the word from fileToCompare.txt is less than the word from Library.txt, keep the word from Library.txt and read the next word from fileToCompare.txt. Otherwise, keep the word from fileToCompare.txt and read the next word form Library.txt.
4. Keep doing that until there are no more words to read.
5. At the end, if there are still any more words left in fileToCompare.txt, read and print them.

The following program follows the above logic and seems to work for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void compareFiles(ifstream& txtf, ifstream& libf)
{
   string txtWord;
   string libWord;
   bool readTxt = true;
   bool readLib = true;

   while ( true )
   {
      if ( readLib )
      {
         // Try to read the next word from the libf
         // If the read is not successful, break out of the loop.
         if ( ! (libf >> libWord) )
         {
            break;
         }
      }

      if ( readTxt )
      {
         // Try to read the next word from the txtf
         // If the read is not successful, break out of the loop.
         if ( ! (txtf >> txtWord) )
         {
            break;
         }
      }

      if ( txtWord == libWord )
      {
         // The same word exists in both files.
         // Read the next words from both files.
         readTxt = readLib = true;
         continue;
      }

      // A word from the text file doesn't exist in the library file.
      // Print the word from the text file if the word from the text file
      // was read in this iteration.
      if ( readTxt )
      {
         cout << txtWord << endl;
      }

      // The next word we read will depend on whether the txtWord is less
      // or greater than libWord.
      if ( txtWord < libWord )
      {
         // Read the next txtWord but keep the current libWord.
         readTxt = true;
         readLib = false;
      }
      else
      {
         // Read the next libWord but keep the current txtWord.
         readTxt = false;
         readLib = true;
      }

      // The above logic can be shortened to.
      // readTxt = (textWord < libWord);
      // readLib = !readTxt;
   }

   // When the previous while loop ends, there might be more words in txtf.
   // Read the remaining words from txtf and print them.
   while ( txtf >> txtWord )
   {
      cout << txtWord << endl;
   }
}

void compareFiles(string const& txt, string const& lib)
{
   ifstream txtf(txt);
   ifstream libf(lib);
   compareFiles(txtf, libf);
}

int main()
{
   string txt="fileToCompare.txt";
   string lib="Library.txt";

   compareFiles(txt, lib);

   return 0;
}
```